# How to abort installation of an uninstallable package with debian packaging

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

**TLDR**

I issued a `dpkg -i PACKAGE` of a newer version of PACKAGE from a newer version of the distrib. It depends on a new libc6 package, thus it failed installing.
Now the package blocks the whole `apt` system.

I just want the system to understand that it can stop wanting to install this package. How would I do that ?

**Longer full version**

My server is on Debian 10. It ships with `mawk-1.3.3` from 1996 (according to `mawk -W version`). On my ubuntu laptop I have `mawk-1.3.4`, the script I wrote on my laptop is not compatible with `mawk-1.3.3`.

So I headed to find a quick way (yeah I know...) to install this on my server. It happens that `mawk-1.3.4` is in `unstable` and `testing` for `sid`, the next debian. I sneakily downloaded the `deb`, and wanted to have a try about  `dpkg -i mawk_1.3.4.20200120-2_amd64.deb`. This failed:

```
 mawk depends on libc6 (>= 2.29); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.28-10.
```

Fair enough, this is **not** the way to go, **how do I go back to before** ? nothing was installed anyway, this shouldn't be too hard, should it ?

**What I tried**

`apt --fix-broken install` want to uninstall `base-files` and `bash`, and I have a very bad feeling about this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  base-files bash mawk rsync
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  base-files mawk (due to base-files) bash
```

I remembered about `dpkg -r` and issued a `dpkg -r mawk` with a little bit of fear for my actual legacy version of `mawk`:

```
 base-files depends on awk; however:                                                                                  
  Package awk is not installed.                                                                                       
  Package mawk which provides awk is to be removed.                                            
                                                                                                                      
dpkg: error processing package mawk (--remove):    
 dependency problems - not removing                               
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mawk
```

So I tried installing `gawk` in a subtle attempt to keep `awk` dependency intact and thus keep `base-files` and `bash` (`mawk` and `gawk` both can provide `awk`). But remember, the install system is blocked, this is what I get from `apt-get install gawk`.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gawk : PreDepends: libsigsegv2 (>= 2.9) but it is not going to be installed
 mawk : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And it seems it doesn't want to let me do anything before "specifying a solution". Which is ironic : **I have a pretty clear and sound solution for this issue**: **stop wanting to install this package**. How can I do that ?

**More info**

As `dpkg` seems to tell me it can't install anything, I assume that nothing have really been touched on the system, all this problem seems to be located in `dpkg`'s state.

So in despair, I've looked in `/var/lib/dpkg` and found mention of the culprit package in `status`, here are some part that seemed interesting:

```
...
Package: mawk
Status: install ok unpacked
Priority: required
...
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 1.3.4.20200120-2
Config-Version: 1.3.3-17+b3
...
```

If anyone has a suggestion. I'm ready to hack my way through files and folder on `/var/lib/dpkg`, but this seems a little silly situation (and it seems that it could be quite common scenario also) that ought to have a nice `dpkg` command to tell politely to `dpkg` to forget about me wanting to install this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think any hack should be necessary; asking `apt` to install the current Debian 10 version should be enough:

```
sudo apt install mawk/buster
```

Alternatively, ask `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/mawk_1.3.3-17+b3_amd64.deb
```

(assuming you still have the package in your APT cache).